# PHP file_exists only working with root:root

Tags: php, linux, centos, plesk, file-exists

if(file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/index.html")) echo 'file exists';

This only returns "file exists" when the owner and group of the file is set to root:root. If I change it to the hostingacc:psacln or hostingacc:psaserv it no longer works.

Is there a way around this please?

Comment: can you show us file permissions and tell us uid and gid of apache or whatever ws are you using?

Comment: I don't wish to disclose anything that might comprise the server. permissions I have set to 777.

Comment: is php engine iterpreting your file after permission change or not?

Answer (score 0):

change owner of the root.

```
chown -r hostingacc:psacln .
```

Comment: The root of the server recursively? I have different hosting accounts each website has their own acc. hostingacc:psacln did not work for index.php or index.html when using if(file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/index.html")) echo 'file exists';

Comment: only root:root returns file exists with the above code Hemc

Comment: Does psacln and psaserv have access to web server ?

Comment: I assume so I am running Plesk 11.5 on centos linux.